# If i bought a domain on google do i still need a DNS resolver like cloudflare?

Tags: dns

I've bought a domain on google and configure it to use `cloudflare` but i'm not sure if i need the cloudflare in the first place, do i need it or i can use the `DNS` section on the google domains normally? (i'm hosting my app on heroku)

Answer (score 0):

What is your domain name? Please explain your question. Normally you do need cloudflare and your DNS resolver service is provided by your hosting provider.